# Is possible get value by name of column in Pandas-Python without order?

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have a csv make in Python where I have different names of columns:

```
  response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="upload.csv"'
  writer = csv.writer(response)
  writer.writerow(['whatever1','whatever2','whatever3','whatever4','whatever5'])
```

I am trying to get the values of these columns by name, but I can only by the order that I have configured.

```
    data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
    io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
    cols = ['whatever1','whatever2','whatever3','whatever4','whatever5']
    df = pd.read_csv(io_string, names=cols)
```

I mean, If I change the order of the columns in excel, it not respect the name of the column, it take the value of the column in order. For example, in excel, if I change the order, Pandas take the column with name whatever2, like whatever1.

```
 whatever2    whatever1
    1                0
    1                0
    2                14
    3                20
```

So, Can I take the values of the column by the name of the column, regardless of the order?

Thanks.

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv(io_string)[cols]`?

Comment: It resolve an error, but I will try: "No columns to parse from file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `usecols` parameter of [`pd.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io_string, usecols=cols)
```

Comment: Fot now, It resolve a error: "Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found" , however, I am following trying.

Comment: @MiguelHerrerosCejas Probably your labels in Excel is not in exact spelling / text format as the names in list `cols`.   You can try to see if you can align the spelling / format and retry.

Comment: It have to be the same because I use the same array for both. Anyway, I tested with a fake array ['column1', 'column2', ' column3'] and I have the same error. I don't know why.

Comment: @MiguelHerrerosCejas  Actually, I'm not quite certain why you have to put dataset in io_string.  Have you tried directly read the CSV by pd.read_csv ?   Your case should use the parm `usecols` for your purpose.  You can try out some test file directly reading the a CSV with labels matching that set in Excel and swap the sequence to test this feature.  If it works, then you can solve the file reading issue.

Comment: @MiguelHerrerosCejas  On your testing of fake array ['column1', 'column2', ' column3'], does the CSV also have these column labels 'column1', 'column2', ' column3' ?   They have to be in exact match in spelling.

Comment: Yep, in the CSV, the column 1 have the same names of the array. I am trying diferents ways, but, If usecols working taking the column by the name, regardless to the order, is only try and try until it work.

Comment: @MiguelHerrerosCejas  Make sure all those listed in `cols` literally match the spellings in the the columns in the Excel.  Also make sure those columns exists in the Excel.  In your fake array, not only column 1 need to match, but also column2, column3 need to exist in the Excel of same spelling.   Note that by using `usecols`, you are specifying the minimum column labels that need to exist in the Excel.  If there is less than these, there will be error.

Comment: Maybe is the way that I use for create CSV. Do not recognise the array like name of columns.

Comment: @MiguelHerrerosCejas  You can also specify `header=0` together with `usecols=cols` to see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried and have the same problem. I think that is the way to create the CSV. I create it with csv.writer and Pandas not recognise the name of the columns.I am trying to change the way to create it.

Comment: Or, let me a question again, sorry but I could not get it. The problem is that pd.read_csv or other way with csv, never read the first row. Even with header=0. 
If I could to get the first row, I make an array and config in usecols=cols , but I do not find the way for do it. 
In io_string, I get column1,column2,colum3 and after an string with value1,value2,value3,value1,value2,value3 
I tested to get data_set or directly  csv_file = request.FILES['csv_file'] but it not working. 
Anyway, I mark your answer, because it is the way.

Comment: @MiguelHerrerosCejas  So, can you see the column labels when opening the csv file by Excel ?   You can also try opening the csv with a text editor and see whether the column labels appear on the first line, separated by comma.    If you can see this, the pd.read_csv should be able to read the columns.  If not, then probably problem when writing to csv in previous steps.

Comment: I got it. I just add a row like a Title, and got the registers like this 
df = pd.read_csv(io_string,header=0)

And now I can take the column by name, anyway I have to test it.

Comment: @MiguelHerrerosCejas  Great that you can take the column by name now.  Remember that there is no need to specify `header=0` when you don't use the `names=` parameter.  Default is already `header=0` when you don't specify `names=` parameter.  But, if you want to select just part of the columns in the csv file and allows the columns in csv to be in any order not following the `cols` list, you have to use `usecols=` parameter.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to use it, because is the best way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You save the file with column's names  , so when you use pd.read_csv  you can use  header parameter to indicate which row has the column's name

```
df = pd.read_csv(file , header = 0 ) 
df.columns
```

Comment: I know it, but when I change the order, It not take the name of the column, just the values in the position when I configured it in array cols = []